# How to grant/revoke an access to Cloud Object Storage resource automatically?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage

I have an iOS App. Would like to explore what is needed to be done to achieve the following:

```
1) The user taps on the map
2) US Census Tract info is requested from database
3) Later the user wants to purchase this tract info.
```

The US Census Tract info would be uploaded to Cloud Object Storage.

There are 70,000 Tracts grouped by US States = 50 + 1 (DC)

I could use SQL Query to select one Census Tract by its ID.

In the iOS App I can use Apple Login and get users' name and email.

The question is how to grant/revoke access to this info automatically
after in-app purchase?

The question is two-fold. Do I have to create 70,000 CSV files and grant them an access to? Or this can be achieved dynamically with SQL?

The second part is - how to automate this process?

Does IBM Cloud has this capability?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that you would use a single [Service ID](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/iam?topic=iam-iamoverview#iamoverview) that would have access to the data sitting in COS, and that a user's access to the underlying data would be handled in your application logic.  The Cloud IAM access policies are not intended for end-users as much as for internal development/operations teams to manage access to various cloud resources.

Depending on the format of the census data, [SQL Query](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/sql-query?topic=sql-query-overview) could be a great way to do it. You could use SQL query to create a new object with the subset of data the user has requested, and then [create a presigned URL](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-presign-url) that will expire in a whatever timeframe is reasonable, allowing the file to be downloaded to the client device.

Comment: Thank you, Nick. Unfortunately I found two big issues in using IBM Cloud. 1) User facing IBM Cloud functions are only ipv4 - my iOS App has to pass the Apple AppStore review which requires ipv6 support. 2) SSL on custom domain - I would like to use Letsencrypt but have to manually renew it every 90 days - not exactly automated Cloud solution. In comparison Google Cloud does everything right in this aspect.

Comment: Yeah, can't disagree on that. We're looking into providing customer-facing ipv6/dualstack endpoints, but I have no idea what the timeline on that might be.  Thanks for the info on the custom domain SSL, I've never tried to set that up and now I'm curious.